# How to enable Webgl feature on Firefox release version (not beta)?

Tags: firefox, webgl

On my Facebook timeline, someone posted an interesting link to [see weapon market in all over the world](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/projects/armsglobe/).

But it is designed on Webgl. Chrome supports it "natively", but Firefox not.

I heard (by Google) that [you can activate Webgl on Firefox beta](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=pt&sl=pt&tl=en&u=http://www.oficinadanet.com.br/artigo/internet/como_ativar_webgl_no_firefox), but that info is perhaps outdated (2010)...

Can I activate Webgl on Firefox release version, at least with some add-on? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in Firefox 22 is is fixed.

Actually, I saw it in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL:

> Mozilla Firefox – WebGL has been enabled on all platforms that have a capable graphics card with updated drivers since version 4.0.[11] Mozilla Firefox 8.0 and newer versions use Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) to control all WebGL cross-domain textures.[12][13]